# Условие IF выполняется не верно

Tags: php

```
$otr = array("ПЧ-25" , "ПЧ-1" , "ПЧ-2" ); // массив на названия
$otr2 = array("ПЧ-30" , "ПЧ-31" , "ПЧ-32"); // массив  на названия

$date1 = date_create($_POST['date_transfer']);
$date2 = date_create($_POST['time_transfer']);

if ($otr = $old_group_transfer){
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    $a = $interval->format('%a');
}
else if ($otr2= $old_group_transfer){
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    $a = $interval->format('%a')*1.5;
}

// if no error occured, continue ....
if(!isset($errMSG))//  дальше идёт добавление в базу
```

вообщем условие if работает но не так, получается по условию я хотел осуществить если переменная равна одному из значений массива то выполнять это действие или если переменная равна другому массиву то выполнять другое действие.

то что написано сверху , он выполняет только первое условие , какое бы значение из двух массивов я бы не взял

Comment: Во-первых непонятно кто такой `$old_group_transfer` откуда он непонятно взялся и что делает и чему равен....Во-вторых вместо сравнения `==` в условиях у вас присваивание `=`..что, конечно же ошибка.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, для сравнения нужно использовать оператор "==", т.к. оператор "=" присваивает значение, возвращает true и у вас выполняется первое условие.
Во-вторых, `$otr` у вас массив. Я так понимаю, нужно проверить, входит ли значение переменной `$old_group_transfer` в этот массив? Тогда нужно использовать функцию `in_array`:

```
$otr = array("ПЧ-25" , "ПЧ-1" , "ПЧ-2" ); // массив на названия
$otr2 = array("ПЧ-30" , "ПЧ-31" , "ПЧ-32"); // массив  на названия

$date1 = date_create($_POST['date_transfer']);
$date2 = date_create($_POST['time_transfer']);

if (in_array($old_group_transfer, $otr)){
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    $a = $interval->format('%a');
}
else if (in_array($old_group_transfer, $otr2)){
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    $a = $interval->format('%a')*1.5;
}

// if no error occured, continue ....
if(!isset($errMSG))//  дальше идёт добавление в базу
```

Comment: вот что мне нужно было , спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Корректный код:

```
$otr = array("ПЧ-25" , "ПЧ-1" , "ПЧ-2" ); // массив на названия
$otr2 = array("ПЧ-30" , "ПЧ-31" , "ПЧ-32"); // массив  на названия

$date1 = date_create($_POST['date_transfer']);
$date2 = date_create($_POST['time_transfer']);
if ($otr == $old_group_transfer ){
  $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
  $a = $interval->format('%a');
}
elseif ($otr2 == $old_group_transfer){
  $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
  $a = $interval->format('%a')*1.5;
}
// if no error occured, continue ....
if(!isset($errMSG))//  дальше идёт добавление в базу
```